# What is the variance of argument types in Scala?

Tags: scala, variance

I've read about Scala having **covariant return types for functions**.
But what about its argument types? What does `FunctionX(T1,...,R)` have to do with all this?

Comment: The argument types are contravariant.

Comment: I found this as an appropriate answer to my question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297019/scala-function-variance-and-overriding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for any `FunctionX` class, you'll see that the return type is co-variant and the argument types are contravariant. For instance, [Function2](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function2) has the signature:

```
Function2[-T1, -T2, +R] extends AnyRef
```

You can spot the `-` and `+` before the type parameters, where `-` means contravariant and `+` covariant.

This means that given

```
class Animal
class Dog extends Animal
```

then

```
Function1[Animal, Dog] <: Function1[Dog, Dog]
Function1[Dog, Dog] <: Function1[Dog, Animal]
```

but

```
Function1[Dog, Animal] </: Function[Dog, Dog]
Function1[Animal, Animal] </: Function[Animal, Dog]
```

In other words, functions *promise no less and require no more*